# Preserving whitespace / indentation in Rails database column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, whitespace, indentation, strip

I have blocks of pseudo-code text stored in a database that get printed off line-by-line and displayed in HTML.

Pseudo-code entered in text column in database:

```
while (counter <= 10) {
  printf("Enter grade: ");
  scanf("%d", &grade);
  total = total + grade;
  counter = counter + 1;
} /* end while */
```

Controller:

```
def index
    @code = Code.first // just a filler for the time being
end
```

Index:

```
- @code.cont.each_line do |line|
    - i += 1
    .line
        %span= i
        %li.line= line
- i = 0
```

Somewhere along the way Ruby automatically strips out any whitespace and just leaves me with the text. I'd like to know how to preserve this so that

This:

```
while (counter <= 10) {
  printf("Enter grade: ");
  scanf("%d", &grade);
  total = total + grade;
  counter = counter + 1;
} /* end while */
```

Doesn't come out as this:

```
while (counter <= 
printf("Enter grade: ");
scanf("%d", &grade);
total = total + grade;
counter = counter + 1;
} /* end while */
```

Comment: Suggest you show the code that handles this.

Comment: Updated with controller and index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your space characters are there, but you can't see them due to the way HTML handles whitespace. Double check this by putting your text into a variable and dumping it to console with a simple `puts my_chunk_of_text`. If the spaces are there (and I can't see why they wouldn't be, based on the code you posted), you have a couple of alternatives:

1) Sandwich your displayed text with the `<pre>` tag, which renders preformatted text. You're going to want to do this in your view, like this:

```
<pre><%= @my_chunk_of_text %></pre>
```

2) Save the text in HTML format, with non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) wherever you want a space to appear, and `<br>` where you need a newline. This code can be rendered in your view with the `html_safe` helper.

```
<%= @my_chunk_of_text.html_safe %>
```

Comment: I printed the column of an record in the rails console and the whitespace was there, yeah. What you can also do is change the CSS to white-space: pre-wrap. But only on the li elements, applying that to a block element messes up the padding and margins.